# Flex SWCs: Are there "debug" and "release" versions for SWC's?

Tags: debugging, flexbuilder, release, swc

Using Flex Builder 3, I do not have an option to export a release build for my SWC. Is there such a concept - "release" versus "debug" versions for a SWC?

Answer (score 1):

Not really.  The Flex linker will do all the optimization/stripping when you link to the SWC to build your final SWF.

Having said that, if the reason you're concerned about this is because you don't want a bloated RSL, you can make a "release" version of the SWC's embedded SWF file by using the optimizer that comes with the SDK.